# How to catch Microsoft Edge's tab process and refresh it

Tags: c#, process, microsoft-edge

## Goal

Be able to open an url in the default browser (if not the default, then just Microsoft Edge, hardcoded) and refresh the page in the future.

## Approach

I think that I would need this (not sure though):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Then I could do something like:

```
Process.Start("http://localhost:5000/");

var list1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdgeCP");
var list2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge");

// and for each of those processes:

SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
SendKeys.SendWait("{F5}");
```

In theory, that should work. But it doesn't. It works with the notepad though. I could send there some string and it's correctly written in the editor. However, I cannot catch the window where the page is opened.

What works ***sometimes*** is catching `ApplicationFrameHost` process and sending key `"{F5}"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

### Bottom line

What seems to be working always is sending `"{F5}` to *all* processes. But that's too dangerous. Why `MicrosoftEdge` processes don't work?

Comment: It sometimes works with ApplicationFrameHost because Edge is so called "Modern" app (think about Windows 10 apps), and such apps are hosted inside "host" process, which (host process) is ApplicationFrameHost.

Comment: Considered using [Web Driver with Microsoft Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/tools/webdriver/)?